# Using Github login with a Django project

Tags: json, django, github, github-api

I'm working on making a site that allows login with Github and I'm using Django for this. I've gotten as far as redirecting the user to the github authorization page, and then redirecting the user to another part of my project after successful authorization. My question is then: How do i extract such things as the users username and other values? I imagine that a JSON object is sent to me, but how do I use it and where do I get it? I have never done anything like this before, so it might be obvious but if anyone could help me it would be appreciated. Bear in mind that I'm a newbie in Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github login is just OAuth. There is full documentation on [Github's dev site](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) on how to do it manually, but you probably want to use one of the many Python libraries which make the process easier such as [python-social-auth](http://python-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [django-allauth](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score 0):

Check out:
https://developer.github.com/guides/basics-of-authentication/

But there is package with this functionality: 
[python-social-auth](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth)